# Android studio not opening in windows 10 hp laptop

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I am using windows10 with 4gb ram and a harddisk 1tb.I have installed android studio where the installation done smoothly but when i run the android studio it is not opening it gets stucked in the loading screen itself even i have downloaded the latest version of android studio,downloaded the latest version of jdk and set the environment variables for both the JDK_HOME and ANDROID_HOME but nothing helps me.

Even i have uninstalled the antivirus but there is no use still and added the line disable android at start in idea.properties file i am having the same problem even i have updated the bios and firmware of my laptop but still there is no use.Even i have uninstalled and reinstalled the studio in different locations also.

Can anyone tell me what makes the android studio not running.I have attached my system properties also

```
 Android Version: 2.1.2
 JDK version:  jdk1.8.0_101
 HP Notebook - 15-ay020tu
 Model #: W6T34PA
```

[Android screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJsGD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your laptop requires more ram at that time by other software because android studio requires more. In 4gb it does not work properly or execution is very slow so you need to increase ram to 8gb at least.

Answer (score 0):

> Try "Run as Administrator".

*Or Install a different version of windows on your laptop in a different partition(**dual-boot** your system). Try Windows 7 and then check if same problem happens.*